# Make sure a new instance of certain component is used

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a feeling this is a "wrong" question to ask, but here goes anyway:

I'm making some sort of quiz app (using redux for state management). (showing the important bits here)

quiz.js

```
<Slider {...sliderSettings} slideIndex={currentQuestionIndex}>
    <Start onStart={() => onNextQuestion()} topicId={topicId}  />

    {
        questions.map((question, ndx) => {
            return (
                <Question {...question} done={onDone} key={`question-${question.id}`} />
            );
        })
    }

    <Result score={score} onRestart={() => onRestart()}/>
</Slider>
```

question.js

```
<div className="question">
    <h2 className="question__text">{ question }</h2>
    <MultipleChoice options={answers} onChange={done} />
</div>
```

multiple-choice.js

```
const
    initialState = {
        selectedValue: null
    };

class MultipleChoice extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = initialState;
    }

    handleChange(value, correct) {
        this.setState({
            selectedValue: value
        });

        this.props.onChange(correct);
    }

    render() {
        const
            { options } = this.props,
            getStateClass = (option, ndx) => {
                let sc = '';

                if (this.state.selectedValue !== null) {
                    if (this.state.selectedValue === ndx) {
                        sc = option.correct ? 'is-correct' : 'is-incorrect';
                    } else if (option.correct) {
                        sc = 'is-correct';
                    }
                }

                return sc;
            };

        return (
            <ul className="multiple-choice">
                { options.map((option, ndx) => {
                    return (
                        <li key={`option-${ndx}`} className={cx('multiple-choice__option', getStateClass(option, ndx))}>
                            <button className="multiple-choice__button" onClick={() => this.handleChange(ndx, option.correct)}>{option.answer}</button>
                        </li>
                    );
                }) }
            </ul>
        );
    };
}

export default MultipleChoice;
```

The problem lies within the rendering of MultipleChoice. It uses internal state to show which answer is wrong and right.

in quiz.js, onRestart dispatches a redux action which updates the store to fetch some new questions and reset the currentQuestionIndex to 0. This all works. 
But somehow, sometimes the MultipleChoice element is "reused" and is still showing the state it had in the previous round of questions. In other words, most of the time a new MultipleChoice gets mounted, but sometimes it isn't. This is react reconciliation, if I understand correctly?

But how do I solve this problem? In my view, MultipleChoice needs its internal state. So should I reset this state somehow? Or make sure a new MultipleChoice gets mounted everytime? Or am I asking the wrong questions here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I looked at [your repository](https://github.com/thomasmattheussen/react-state-problem), and the issue, as correctly [noted in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39572866/458193) is that your `<Question>` (and thus inner `<MultipleChoice>`) components **never unmount, so they keep their state.**

Normally this doesn’t come up often in React because people usually want the state to be preserved while the component is in the tree. When the state is no longer needed, people usually stop including components in the `render()` method, and React unmounts them. Next time they are rendered, their state gets reset.

The state does *not* get reset in your example because you *always* keep the `<Question>`s visible, even between the quiz runs. You can see that `<Question>`s are already mounted before we begin the quiz, and stay mounted after it ends:

[image: stale-questions]

So how can we force React to reset their state? There are three options:

- You may cause them to unmount. Next time they get mounted, they’ll have a new state. This is usually the simplest solution, because you don’t actually display the questions on the initial “start quiz” page. For example, you can do this by adding `currentQuestionIndex > 0 &&` guard before rendering `questions.map(...)` in the `render()` method of `<Questions>`.
- You may pass new `key`s to them that don’t match previous `key`s. You are currently using `question-${question.id}` as the `key` right now but that will produce the same key for the same question even if you retry the quiz. To solve this, you could introduce a new state variable (either in Redux or in top-level component state), for example, `quizAttemptIndex`, and increment it on any new attempt. Then you could change the key to be `question-${quizAttemptIndex}-${question.id}`. This way attempting a quiz another time would reset the internal state of the question (as well as cause it to remount).
- Finally, if you’d rather not destroy the DOM completely by passing a different `key`, you could pass `quizAttemptIndex` (explained in the previous section) as a prop to `<MultipleChoice>`. Then, inside it, you could `this.setState({ selectedValue: null })` inside `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` if `nextProps.quizAttemptIndex !== this.props.quizAttemptIndex`.

You can choose either solution depending on how important it is for you to keep the questions mounted all the time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want your MultipleChoice component to refresh its state when you want it to do so. But as you are using react state in your component, as long as your component doesn't unmount, your react state in your MultipleChoice keeps its latest state.

This behaviour is expected from react state, because mostly you want to use it for internal behaviour. Maybe you want to toggle some ui data in your component, when some button or something triggers your component to do so. Or you want to control your input forms etc.

But what you expect should be accomplished in redux state. Your component should be reusable which doesn't care where it mounted. You pass your mounted-place-related data to your MultipleChoice with props, which is taken from redux. So now you have a reusable component. Don't spend much time about mounting etc. You might check react-redux repositories on github to get familiar with how to shape your project's data flow. When to use redux state to make desicions or handle state in your component by react state.

Comment: you understood correctly I think. I already thought of the solution you proposed, but that feels pretty weird to me. I am now left with the feeling: "If this isn't a case for internal state, then what is?"